# Einstein chatbot able to take file uploads

Tags: lightning-web-components, einstein, chatbot

I have a requirement for an einstein chatbot which will be able to take file uploads. Can anyone give me some directions?

I have been looking for a decent solution for my requirement, but lack of information and documentation is hitting my fresher brain hard... Any help or information is appreciated.

Comment: Does [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bots_service_enhanced_file_inbound.htm&type=5) help?